# Flutter widgets binding inside initState() to open another page not working

Tags: flutter

I know it may be a sign of code smell to push another page from within the initState() of another widget but this is the only work around I can do for now. My question is, when I have the below function, the new page doesn't show, or sometimes it seems to show for one frame and disappears. Anyone have any idea why it wouldn't just work.

Note that I do continue to do work in the current widget and setState() may be called multiple times.

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/newPage');
  });
    
}
```

Comment: If it appears (as a blink) maybe something in the new page is also doing a pop, have you tried with a minimal reproducible project (a scaffold opening another scaffold page)

Comment: There's nothing in the new page doing a pop. It rarely appears as a blink, most times it just doesn't show. I'm pretty confused.

Comment: can you show a bit of what else is doing the iniState or the build method, addPostFrameCallback is called at the end of a frame, maybe it didn't find a frame to work at all

Comment: Something like that happens to me once while calling another function in addPostFrameCallback, try using Future.microtask to see if there is a difference